# Adding elements to list after get 2 or more inputs on Python

Tags: python, arrays, append, element, addition

```
def take_info(arr2,arr, number):

     arr[0] = number
     name = input()
     arr[1] = name
     grade = int(input())
     arr[2] = grade
     second_grade = int(input())
     arr[3] = second_grade
     arr2. append(arr)

def main():
     number = int(input())
     arr = [0] * 4
     count =1
     arr2 = // ? I dont know how to do it, range must be equal to count but how? Thats the point 1.
     while number>0:
           take_info(arr2,arr,number)
           count +=1
           number = int(input())

main()
```

take_info function must return while ' number >0 ', when the number is 0 or less than 0 loop would end. And I want to add these values and name to a list and the other list's each element should be list. Could anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Any time you're repeating something, you probably want to use a loop.  If you're using a loop to build a list, you probably want to use a list comprehension.

```
arr = [input() for _ in range(3)]
```

---

Given your updated question, I might do it like this:

```
def take_info(number):
    return [number, input(), int(input()), int(input())]

def main():
    return [take_info(number) for number in range(int(input()))]

print(main())
```

If it's important that the numbers count down instead of up, you can do that by modifying the `range` call so that it goes from N-1 to 0 instead of 0 to N-1.

Comment: but I want to write something different for each of the input, thats why I'm not doing like this

Comment: @Archie Maybe you should update your question to reflect a better-specified version of your problem, including some representation of the difficult details.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to have space separated inputs in one line, you can use this:

```
my_list = list(map(str,input().split()))
for i in range(len(my_list)):
   if (isinstance(my_list(i), int)):
      temp = int(my_list(i))
      my_list.pop(i)
      my_list.insert(i, temp)
```

Input: Car Hockey Cricket

my_list = ['Car', 'Hockey', 'Cricket']

Ofcourse, the data type would be the same here. You'd need to make changes after appending incase of int, float, etc.

Comment: I want to write 4 data in it and there is 2 data type, ones is int and other one is string,

Comment: Could u check edit? I just fixed it out maybe its clear now

Comment: First of all, what are you trying to define "arr2" as? Secondly, are you trying to initialise "arr" as a list of fixed size? Could you give an example of how you want the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

The stereotype of Python is that “everything is a dict”.  Your application might be such a case.

One way to organize the data you have coming in might be a dict where each entry is also a dict.

```py
def take_info():
    record = dict()
    record['name'] = input('Name: ')
    record['grade'] = int(input('Grade: '))
    record['second_grade'] = int(input('Second grade: '))
    return record

def main():
    course_records = dict()
    count = 0
    number = int(input('ID number: '))
    while number > 0:
           course_records[number] = take_info()
           count +=1
           number = int(input('ID number: '))
```